# How do I fix WordPress MySQL tables in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

Backstory:

I used MAMP on Mac to set up a local dev server and database for creating a WordPress site. All was going well. Yesterday, the MySQL server did not start up, so I took the advice of an answer on StackOverflow to remove the ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, and ibdata1 files from the mysql56 folder. This started a chain of events that ended up corrupting my tables on phpMyAdmin.

I kept the ib_ and database files, and after reinstalling MAMP, have placed them in MAMP/db/mysql, but now have errors with my tables in phpMyAdmin (see attachment). All of the tables have the same type of errors and are listed as 0 bytes. I've tried dropping the table, setting up a new database, downloading fresh copies of MAMP, etc. How can I fix these tables so I can export MySQL?

phpMyAdmin Errors:

> Backtrace: 'Warning in
>   ./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#1‌​339
>   Illegal string offset 'Data_length' Backtrace
>   ./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#1‌​258:
>   PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->ge‌​tTableStats()
>   ./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#3‌​54:
>   PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->di‌​splayStructure(
>   array, array, array, boolean false, array, array, )
>   ./tbl_structure.php#49:
>   PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->in‌​dexAction()'

Comment: Instead of taking a screenshot of the errors I would advise making an [edit] and including the error messages so they could be better examined.

Comment: Backtrace: 'Warning in ./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#1339
Illegal string offset 'Data_length'

Backtrace

./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#1258: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->getTableStats()
./libraries/controllers/table/TableStructureController.php#354: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->displayStructure(
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
array,
array,
)
./tbl_structure.php#49: PMA\libraries\controllers\table\TableStructureController->indexAction()'

Comment: The whole data directory is the "database". If you take parts out and replace other parts with new files, you will probably brake something (you wouldn't do that with your car, but at least with a database you can make a backup/copy before you try anything). If you don't have a backup (sometimes an older backup is enough), you are probably out of luck. Anyway, this question would better be suited on dba.stackexchange.com (as it is not about programming), maybe someone has an idea there.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an issue where the table and/or column is defined in UPPERCASE. I also faced a similar issue and checked open issues on GitHub and got the following link.

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13178

I suggest that after the creation of your table or editing the structure of the table, go back to phpmyadmin home and come again to the same table. You won't see that error. This is my personal workaround.

Comment: Could you check [my comment on phpMyAdmin GitHub issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13178#issuecomment-345444217) ? I have a WP site installed locally and suddenly it became unavailable, using MAMP for server part (Apache & MySQL + phpMyAdmin)