# Illegal string offset 'Data_length'/'Index_length' for every row of table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Learning PHP/mySQL etc, When I create a table with phpmyadmin using xampp I get this error for every single row:

> Warning in .\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#1339
>    Illegal string offset 'Data_length'
>
> Backtrace
>
> .\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#1278: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->getTableStats()
>   .\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#377: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->displayStructure(
>   array,
>   array,
>   array,
>   ,
>   array,
>   array,
>   )
>   .\tbl_structure.php#57: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->indexAction()
>   Warning in .\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#1342
>    Illegal string offset 'Index_length'
>   Backtrace
>
> .\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#1278: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->getTableStats()
>   .\libraries\classes\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController.php#377: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->displayStructure(
>   array,
>   array,
>   array,
>   ,
>   array,
>   array,
>   )
>   .\tbl_structure.php#57: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Table\TableStructureController->indexAction()

I can't seem to figure it out, this occurs whenever I try create a table.
My table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Graham. You should include the code you wrote in your question to help us better advise with your issue. Here are SO's guidelines on how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix WordPress MySQL tables in phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636575/how-do-i-fix-wordpress-mysql-tables-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: @DarraghEnright I have no code so far, I have simply created the table.

Comment: Did you write the `create table` statement?

Comment: I created the table using the myphpadmin gui, if you check the picture you can see the columns etc. But it still gives me this error.

Comment: I defined the table manually in mySQL and it worked, however I would still like to know why I got that error if you have the time!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? What version of PHPMyAdmin is/was this? Looks like the PHPMyAdmin version is not compatible with PHP 7.1+

Comment: Linked with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460806/phpmyadmin-illegal-string-offset-data-length

Answer (score 6):

**Do these steps:**

1. Open your MySQL configuration file: [drive]\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

   OR

   On XAMMP panel in MySQL row > config > my.ini
2. Look up for: # The MySQL server *[mysqld]*
3. Add this right below it:  `lower_case_table_names = 2`
4. Save the file and restart MySQL service

Comment: It works but now all the capital letters in my table name are showing as lowercase :( I just want to use camelCase everywhere in my entire project. And my ini is in xamp/bin/mysql/my.ini