# Cannot access my mysql tables after install WARNING Illegal string offset

Tags: mysql, installation, mamp

I'm using Mojave 10.14.6 and I moved my /MAMP/ 5.7 => 7.4.2. folder to keep a BACKUP. (MAMP was freezing all the time, and I had to contantly reboot it).

Then I installed the latest MAMP version 6.3. with PHP 7.4.12 MYSQL 5.7.32 which also has folder /db/mysql57/

Nothing worked, but at the end I managed to get phpMyAdmin to open, and finally to show my BACKED UP tables.

To be able to see the tables I just copied the BACKED UP /db/mysql57/ folder. But I was getting some errors ( I believe the same errors as I'm getting now with the old version ... ( see image ).

I tried installing the latest phpMyAdmin and didn't help. Since I didn't manage to fix it, I said, I'll move the BACKUP copy to /Applications/ and renamed the new one to /MAMP BAK/

So, NOW, I wanted to go back to my previous working version ( the one I BACKED UP ), but the working version is giving me the errors below. I rather have the new version.

I found 2 main solutions:

1. it's because it had capital letters on the table, (which is my case too, but it was working before with capital letters, I have hundreds of tables, I cannot lowercase all of them). I tried to create a new table in lowercase, to see if that was the problem, but it doens't even allow me to create a table.
2. or that I need to clean the CACHE, which I did and rebooted the macbook, and still gives me the errors.

So, I assume that the install, installed something else that isn't in the /MAMP/ folder.

EDIT: with the OLD version Apache doesn't even light up. Mysql Server is Green. So,  NOW I went back to the NEW VERSION. I tried: Tools:Check/Repair/Upgrade database tables.

```
wall.message_share                                 OK
wall.messages                                      OK
wall.page_names
Error    : Table 'wall.page_names' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
wall.pages
Error    : Table 'wall.pages' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
wall.profile_views                                 OK
wall.template                                      OK
wall.user_uploads                                  OK
....
```

And the Upgrade:

```
...
Error    : Table 'wall.page_names' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
wall.pages
Error    : Table 'wall.pages' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
Upgrade process completed successfully.
Checking if update is needed.
```

It's like if the NEW version, doesn't recognize the old version's tables. Or like if they were corrupted, but as I said, I just moved the folder.

With the NEW VERSION I created a new table in CAPS and works fine. But the old ones keep on giving the error.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAIBz.png

So, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55277978/illegal-string-offset-data-length-index-length-for-every-row-of-table/56592275) says to put " lower_case_table_names = 2 " in my.ini

But I have no my.cnf So, I got this one: https://gist.github.com/fragje/9953959

and now the server doesn't work. The On/Off button is Orange.

```
[client]
password = root
port    = 8888
socket    = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port    = 8889
socket    = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8
lower_case_table_names = 2
```

...
I don't find the error, the ports seem fine.

I FOUND 1 error, with this:

```
# thread_concurrency = 8
```

... the server is GREEN. but still this command lower_case_table_names = 2 doesn't solve the lowercase issue.

I RUN AGAIN: Tools:Check/Repair/Upgrade database tables with smaller DB and still says table doesn't exist. So, it will never fix them.

And since I put this "lower_case_table_names = 2" the table I created gives the same error.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to restore database by copying files. Why didn’t you use mysqldump and restore with MySQL itself?

Comment: I didn't know there was a better way. I thought with macs you could just copy the folder and it had all included with it, but I can see now that it's not the case. I know with windows is never the case.

Comment: It does not depend on windows or Mac here. It is just MySQL which is not working that way.  Don’t you have a time Maschine backup you can restore?

Comment: Yes, and I recovered the MAMP folder. But that's the same I already had moved to keep a backup, and just that folder took 24 hours. So, if I have to recover the entire computer I"ll be down many days. I feel I'm so close to get it working. It has to be something with the CAPS. But I'm also looking into the mysqldump you recommended.

Comment: If it doesn’t matter to restore the whole computer, you can do very quick pressing ctrl-r while booting. Then you can restore the whole harddisk from the TM quickly. Everything else might lead to more problems in the future. As I can remember newer versions of mamp are using the Application folder for some data. So you might look there

Comment: Great Claus, I'll try that out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I ment the „Application Support“ folder not the application of course

Comment: Thanks Claus, at the end I didn't have to touch "Application Support", and I managed to backup 1 database using mysqldump. So, so far very good, but it takes 28Gb !!!